# ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'

Tags: python, ubuntu, apt-get, dpkg

Стоит такая ось: linux mint 17.2 cinnamon 64-bit

Возникает следующая ошибка:

```
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
обновлено 0, установлено 0 новых пакетов, для удаления отмечено 0 пакетов, и 0 пакетов не обновлено.
не установлено до конца или удалено 44 пакетов.
После данной операции, объём занятого дискового пространства возрастёт на 0 B.
Настраивается пакет libxml2:amd64 (2.9.1+dfsg1-3ubuntu4.8) …
Настраивается пакет libxml2:i386 (2.9.1+dfsg1-3ubuntu4.8) …
Настраивается пакет google-chrome-stable (51.0.2704.103-1) …
Настраивается пакет libgd3:amd64 (2.1.0-3ubuntu0.1) …
Настраивается пакет libgd3:i386 (2.1.0-3ubuntu0.1) …
Настраивается пакет libnl-3-200:amd64 (3.2.21-1ubuntu3) …
Настраивается пакет libnl-genl-3-200:amd64 (3.2.21-1ubuntu3) …
Настраивается пакет libnl-route-3-200:amd64 (3.2.21-1ubuntu3) …
Настраивается пакет python-ldb (1:1.1.24-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) …
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-ldb (--configure):
 подпроцесс установлен сценарий post-installation возвратил код ошибки 1
Настраивается пакет python-tdb (1.3.8-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) …
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-tdb (--configure):
 подпроцесс установлен сценарий post-installation возвратил код ошибки 1
dpkg: зависимости пакетов не позволяют настроить пакет python-samba:
 python-samba зависит от python-ldb (>= 1.1.2~), однако:
  Пакет python-ldb пока не настроен.
 python-samba зависит от python-tdb, однако:
  Пакет python-tdb пока не настроен.

dpkg: error processing package python-samba (--configure):
 проблемы зависимостей — оставляем не настроенным
dpkg: зависимости пакетов не позволяют настроить пакет samba-common-bin:
 samba-common-bin зависит от python-samba, однако:
  Пакет python-samba пока не настроен.

dpkg: error processing package samba-common-bin (--configure):
 проблемы зависимостей — оставляем не настроенным
dpkg: зависимости пакетов не позволяют настроить пакет samba:
 samba зависит от python-samba, однако:
  Пакет python-samba пока не настроен.
 samba зависит от samba-common-bin (= 2:4.3.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.14.04.3), однако:
  Пакет samba-common-bin пока не настроен.

dpkg: error processing package samba (--configure):
 проблемы зависимостей — оставляем не настроенным
Настраивается пакет yandex-browser-beta (16.6.0.6383-1) …
Настраивается пакет apt-utils (1.0.1ubuntu2.14) …
Настраивается пакет libklibc (2.0.3-0ubuntu1.14.04.1) …
Настраивается пакет klibc-utils (2.0.3-0ubuntu1.14.04.1) …
Настраивается пакет apt-transport-https (1.0.1ubuntu2.14) …
Настраивается пакет dosfstools (3.0.26-1ubuntu0.1) …
Настраивается пакет openssh-client (1:6.6p1-2ubuntu2.7) …
Настраивается пакет openssl (1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.19) …
Настраивается пакет adobe-flashplugin (1:20160512.1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) …
update-alternatives: используется /usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/libflashplayer.so для предоставления /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/flashplugin-alternative.so (mozilla-flashplugin) в автоматический режим
Настраивается пакет firefox (47.0+linuxmint1+rosa) …
Please restart all running instances of firefox, or you will experience problems.
Настраивается пакет firefox-locale-en (47.0+linuxmint1+rosa) …
Настраивается пакет gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0 (0.9.8.8-0ubuntu7.3) …
Настраивается пакет gir1.2-soup-2.4 (2.44.2-1ubuntu2.1) …
Настраивается пакет libdpkg-perl (1.17.5ubuntu5.6) …
Настраивается пакет libnm-glib-vpn1 (0.9.8.8-0ubuntu7.3) …
Настраивается пакет libpq5 (9.3.13-0ubuntu0.14.04) …
Настраивается пакет linux-firmware (1.127.22) …
Настраивается пакет linux-libc-dev:amd64 (3.13.0-88.135) …
Настраивается пакет mintsystem (8.0.8) …
update-rc.d: warning: default stop runlevel arguments (0 1 6) do not match mintsystem Default-Stop values (none)
 System start/stop links for /etc/init.d/mintsystem already exist.
Настраивается пакет poppler-utils (0.24.5-2ubuntu4.4) …
Настраивается пакет postgresql-client-9.3 (9.3.13-0ubuntu0.14.04) …
Настраивается пакет postgresql-9.3 (9.3.13-0ubuntu0.14.04) …
 * Starting PostgreSQL 9.3 database server                                                                                                                       [ OK ] 
Настраивается пакет postgresql-contrib-9.3 (9.3.13-0ubuntu0.14.04) …
Настраивается пакет python-libxml2 (2.9.1+dfsg1-3ubuntu4.8) …
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-libxml2 (--configure):
 подпроцесс установлен сценарий post-installation возвратил код ошибки 1
Настраивается пакет simple-scan (3.12.3-0ubuntu1) …
Настраивается пакет ssh-askpass-gnome (1:6.6p1-2ubuntu2.7) …
Настраивается пакет thunderbird (1:38.8.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) …
Настраивается пакет thunderbird-gnome-support (1:38.8.0+build1-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) …
Настраивается пакет kpartx (0.4.9-3ubuntu7.13) …
Настраивается пакет kpartx-boot (0.4.9-3ubuntu7.13) …
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Настраивается пакет libc6-dbg:amd64 (2.19-0ubuntu6.9) …
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.9) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu4.3) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-38-generic
Warning: No support for locale: ru_RU.utf8
При обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки:
 python-ldb
 python-tdb
 python-samba
 samba-common-bin
 samba
 python-libxml2
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

> No module named 'ConfigParser'

- [Debian. Не работает apt-get install](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/534163/178576)
- [Настройка django, python в Debian 8 Jessie](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/440002/178576)
- [Не могу установить python-webtest](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/458399/178576)

причина проблемы: установленная не из репозитория «очень свежая» версия интерпретатора *python*.

один из возможных вариантов решения, например, в этом ответе: [Ошибка при установке GIMP: “ImportError: No module named _sysconfigdata_nd”](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/535813/178576)